# Resize Images on Azure blob after uploading them

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm uploading images using Web API to Azure Blob, I want to resize the uploaded image in the same container if the dimensions are greater than 900*900 and then create a thumbnail image in another container.

I created an Azure function to do that, it creates a thumbnail image but I don't know how to resize the original one in case it is greater than 900*900.

```
using ImageResizer;

public static void Run(
Stream image,                           // input blob, large size
Stream imageSmall,
Stream imageMedium)  // output blobs
{
    var imageBuilder = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current;
    var size = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Small];

    imageBuilder.Build(
       image, imageSmall,
       new ResizeSettings(size.Item1, size.Item2, FitMode.Max, null), 
       false);

image.Position = 0;
size = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Medium];

imageBuilder.Build(
    image, imageMedium,
    new ResizeSettings(size.Item1, size.Item2, FitMode.Max, null), false);
}

public enum ImageSize
{
  ExtraSmall, Small, Medium
}

private static Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>>()
    {
        { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, Tuple.Create(320, 200) },
        { ImageSize.Small,      Tuple.Create(640, 400) },
        { ImageSize.Medium,     Tuple.Create(800, 600) }
    };
```

Comment: Please, format your code better.

Comment: Also, ImageResizer is paid only library, so no way to test your code.

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: This an Azure function template.

Comment: It resizes the original one in a new blob,I want to replace the original one in the same blob in case the size greater than 900*900

Comment: Show us your code which calls function Run. In order to replace azure Blob you have to delete it first and then put new item there.

Comment: I you just upload a new stream/byte array using the same name it will override the old one

Comment: What do you mean with Azure Blob? You upload your image into an azure Storage as Blob? If Yes --> what Interface do you use? AZ CLI, Powershell CMDLETS, .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on azure portal and use BlobTrigger. However,when I tried to add Output path as input path, it always not executed. When I use random name of blob name in output path, I found it would execute circling.

So, I suggest that you could try to use **dynamic output bindings** in function to avoid it.

For dynamic output bindings, you could leverage the following code snippet:

```
var attributes = new Attribute[]
{    
    new BlobAttribute("{container-name}/{blob-name}"),
    new StorageAccountAttribute("joeystorage") //connection string name for storage connection
};
using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
{
    writer.Write(userBlobText);
}
```

[image]
**Note**: The above code would create the target blob if not exists and override the existing blob if it exists. Moreover, if you do not specify the `StorageAccountAttribute`, your target blob would be create into the storage account based on the app setting `AzureWebJobsStorage`.

Additionally, you could follow [Azure Functions imperative bindings](http://blog.xebia.com/azure-functions-imperative-bindings/) for more details.

The detailed code:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using ImageResizer;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task Run(
Stream image,   // input blob, large size
Binder binder,string blobname,string blobextension,TraceWriter log)  // output blobs
{
    var attributes = new Attribute[]
    {    
        new BlobAttribute($"container/{blobname}.{blobextension}"),

        new StorageAccountAttribute("joeystorage") //connection string name for storage connection
    };
    CloudBlockBlob blob =await binder.BindAsync<CloudBlockBlob>(attributes);
    var imageBuilder = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current;
    var size = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Small];

    Stream outStream=new MemoryStream();
    imageBuilder.Build(
       image,outStream,
       new ResizeSettings(size.Item1, size.Item2, FitMode.Max, null),false);
      blob.UploadFromStream(outStream);
}

public enum ImageSize
{
  ExtraSmall, Small, Medium
}

private static Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>>()
    {
        { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, Tuple.Create(320, 200) },
        { ImageSize.Small,      Tuple.Create(640, 400) },
        { ImageSize.Medium,     Tuple.Create(800, 600) }
    };
```